# How do you "align" a sort across multiple vectors?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am looking for a way to do the following:

```
std::vector<char> v1{'a', 'z', 'b', 'c'};
std::vector<int> v2{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::special_sort(v1, v2);

// Output:
// v1: a, b, c, z
// v2: 1, 3, 4, 2
```

So `v1` should be aligned by the result of a `sort` on `v1`.

Is there a function in the standard that does `special_sort`?

What is such a sort called?

Comment: Cannot you use a single vector where each element is the pair? E.g., `std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> v{{'a', 1}, {'z', 2}. ...}`. In such a way the solution is pretty straightforward

Comment: Thought about that as well, but its not really an option

Comment: You can use a predicate that refers to v1 and v2 by index, and pass in a `vector<size_t>` that represents the index position (pre-initialized from 0 ... size-1).  I assume v1 and v2 are same size.  Then the sorted index position can be used to construct a new v1 and new v2 from the old ones.